# How to enabled hermes engine with custom build types in React Native v71 app?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-hermes

Hermes was initially enabled when i picked up this project, this is *not* an expo app. before i added custom build types, the entire buildtypes, subprojects, and application.all objects were entirely commented out by previous developer.

once uncommented, there were no issues with builds & installs or launches

but once i added a custom build type, "releaseStaging", all of a sudden there were issues launching (not even a splash screen). no issues with gradle, or building, or installing.

however, the application will not launch on android. just continual "failed to launch" errors. specifically from logcat:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libhermes.so`

it seems obviously related to the JS engine condition:

```
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
```

ive combed through several github issues while troubleshooting, no fixes identified seem to target RN v71. This is an issue if you just create a new react-native project and add a custom build type.

i've tried adding the following and cleaning gradle, but none work:
`releaseStagingImplementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")`

```
   releaseStagingImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
```

android/app/build.gradle looks like this:

```
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", '""'
        }
        releaseStaging {
            // This build type is named specifically - if changing, ensure "release" is included in string, react.gradle explicitly looks for it 

            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", "staging-deployment-key"
            // Note: It is a good idea to provide matchingFallbacks for the new buildType you create to prevent build issues
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // Detox-specific additions to pro-guard
            proguardFile "${rootProject.projectDir}/../node_modules/detox/android/detox/proguard-rules-app.pro"
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", "prod-deployment-key"
        }
    }

dependencies {
    implementation('androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1') {
        version {
            strictly '1.3.1'
        }
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0")
    // implementation("com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0")
    // implementation("com.microsoft.identity:common:3.6.7")
    // implementation("com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:2.2.3")
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:6.9.0' 
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
    androidTestImplementation('com.wix:detox:+')
    androidTestImplementation('com.linkedin.testbutler:test-butler-library:2.2.1')
}
```

How is this being solved? I assume its common for just adding a buildtype and building an app.

Comment: did you find a solution?